# Using the SOAP API, is there any way to tell if a sendEmail result has bounced?

Tags: soap-api, send-email, send-an-email

I see in the SOAP API official documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail_emailresult.htm) that even when a success response is returned from `sendEmail` / `SendEmailResult`, an email could have bounced. I tried setting the `targetObjectId` per the documentation for `sendEmail` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm), but even then the Acitviy History doesn't mention that the email bounced, and I did not receive the bounced email back to sender (set up per [these instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5)).

For some customers it is critical to know if an email has not been received. Are there any other ways using the SOAP API to establish whether a email bounced / failed to send properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [Email Bounce Management](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5), which flags records that bounce either temporarily (e.g. because of storage) or permanently (e.g. invalid address). This will set EmailBouncedDate and EmailBouncedReason, as well as the IsBounced field on the EmailMessage record. Please note that this feature must be enabled in order to detect bounces that you can query through the API. Emails are logged as well, but you must [manually request those logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_logs_edit.htm&type=5), and so this is unsuitable for your purpose.

Comment: Hmm, email bounce management was the second link I mentioned in the question, but I did not see the bounced email go back to the sender. I also didn't see the EmailBouncedDate or EmailBouncedReason set on the Contact record.